# It takes double times to login comparing to SAS based NAS when roaming profile is provided from All flash NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, roaming-profile, vdi

I'm going to migrate the NAS storage from a SAS-based one to an all-flash one. Purpose of NAS is Windows roaming profiles for virtual desktop.

I'm in trouble when user login using roam profiles provided from All flash NAS, it takes double times comparing to SAS based NAS.
Simple file copy speed from All flash NAS to user desktop is faster than copying from SAS based NAS.

Both NASs are on same vLAN and user log in with same user profiles.
User profiles size is 100MB, number of files in user profiles are 100.

My questions are:

1. Are there any differences in file copy process between simple file copying and retrieving user profiles?
2. How can I up the speed of retrieving user profiles without reducing size of it ?

Comment: Could be simple sequential IO versus random IO. Depending on the exact hardware involved, the SAS spinning hard drives may very well have higher sequential IO performance than your flash NAS.

Comment: What's the RAID config on both NASs? Do you use caching on them?